# Why is Excel truncating my normal numbers?

Tags: microsoft-excel-2007

I open MS Excel 2007 and I write:
50
and Excel changes that into 0.5
I write 500
and excel changes that into 5
I write 5000
and excel changes that into 50
and so on and so on.

It is driving me crazy!. If I write 50000 in the cell, I want to see 50000 in the cell.
Why is excel acting this way? What did I do? 
please help.

All I wanted to do is change dot and comma. Dot for thousands and comma as decimal. And then all the numbers got messed up since then.
For example: I wanted 50.000 (and not 50,000) or 1.0 (and not 1,0)

Comment: "All I wanted to do is change dot and comma. Dot for thousands and comma as decimal. And then all the numbers got messed up since then"...  It sounds like you made a custom format?  Do they show correctly if you use a standard format?

Comment: Yeah, revert those changes and Excel will show the numbers correctly...

Comment: Does this happen in a new Excel file or is it just in a single file? if the latter, then what was said in comments is correct. In not, please try to describe as clearly and completely as possible what you did that made Excel act this way.

Answer (score 1):

Yea, I think I know what I did wrong.
In Excel Options-Advanced ... I enabled "Automatically insert a decimal point" which caused 50000 to display as 500.
Now, everything is ok.
Thanks all for immediate response.

Comment: Welcome to Super User.  You appear to be replying to your own question from a second new account, if you like the community and are looking to benefit more from the great people here I would recommend registering an account and having your current accounts merged as the account used to answer will not have control of the question.  See our help centre information: [I accidentally created two accounts; how do I merge them?](http://superuser.com/help/merging-accounts)